# having cleaned/ cleaning

Tags: word-usage, tense

I have finished cleaning the floor and my friend tell me:

> 1. Thank you for cleaning the floor

or

> 2. Thank you for having cleaned the floor

I would use the second sentence because the cleaning is finished.
I cannot find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is thanking you for the action of cleaning the floor, so the first sentence is correct.

"*Thank you for having cleaned the floor*" can be understood, but is literally thanking you for *the fact that* you have cleaned the floor, not for cleaning the floor itself, which is nonsensical. It sounds more like expressing a feeling of gratitude that the floor was cleaned, rather than expressing appreciation to you for your work

Comment: Okay but I did not understand this sentence "is literally thanking you for the fact that you have cleaned the floor, not for cleaning the floor itself" ?

Answer (score 1):

Construction logic:

**Cleaning the floor** is not amusing.

Usage: to thank someone **for** something or **for doing** something.

**Thank you for cleaning the floor.**

Answer (score 0):

Untensed forms of verbs (infinitives, participles etc) can indeed be moved into the (relative) past by using *have* with the past participle; for example:

> I had hoped *to have finished* by now.

> *Having seen* the film before, I didn't pay much attention to it.

But it's rather rare to use the "gerund" (verbal noun) in this way, and I think this is for the reason that gotube mentioned. A gerund denotes an action or a state. *Cleaning the room* denotes an action, that it makes sense to thank somebody for. *Having cleaned the room* denotes a state: the state you are in when you earlier cleaned the room.